# WPF MVVM - where do I keep windows instances?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I'm developing an application with one main window and few more windows like ProjectProperties window, UsersData window etc. I want these windows to be created only once (for example at application start) and just hide/unhide them when needed. They will be disposed only when application is closed. Where should I keep the instances of these windows? Should I keep their ViewModels instances in the MainWindowViewModel class? What about the Views (keep them in MainWindowView)? How do I hide/unhide them?

I don't want to use WVVM Light, Calibrum etc. Just pure MVVM.

I'm new to WPF and MVVM so please be specific as much as possible.

Comment: You could for example create an ApplicationService class where you create and keep references to all windows and view models. Create an instance of this class when the application starts.

Comment: are you talking about free floating windows? ... or do you mean modal dialogs?

Comment: We used Autofac Container and registered Windows as single instance. Then you could inject them where you want.

Comment: @CHS These windows are free floating windows.

Comment: @mm8 Not a bad idea but it will mix Views and ViewModels isn't that against MVVM?

Comment: @Alex hmm this is what I tried to avoid but I'll read about Autofac anyway.

Comment: Create two classes then, one window service and one application/view model service.

Comment: @Arthur There is nothing against MVVM with the ApplicationService as long as the View knows the ViewModel that will know the Model. ApplicationService is not View, not ViewModel, not Model. It is a service that will manage Views/ViewModels

Comment: @Arthur Have a look at https://github.com/Microsoft/BikeSharing360_MobileApps and the NavigationService

Answer (score 0):

This link has a good toturial about navigation (i think that is what you want) with pure MVVM.

https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/

Where the views are "stored", is in here:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:HomeViewModel}">
        <local:HomeView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ProductsViewModel}">
        <local:ProductsView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

That is also the relation between Views and ViewModels.

**EDIT:** As your new to MVVM, i also advise you to read this one https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/

Hope it helps.